# How to make a playlist to play continuously in react music palyer

Tags: reactjs, audio, use-ref, react-player

I am new at react, so don't be too harsh.
I'm building music player and I have one last thing left - I can't figure out how to play next song after current one ended.

Here is my code

```
  const [tracks, setTracks] = useState([])
  const [currentTrack, setCurrentTrack] = useState({})
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false)
  const [songLength, setSongLength] = useState(0)
  const [songProgress, setSongProgress] = useState(0)


 useEffect(() => {
    let timeOut = null

    const onPlaying = () => {
      if (!audioRef.current.paused) {
        const { duration } = audioRef.current
        const { currentTime } = audioRef.current

        setSongProgress((currentTime / duration) * 100)
        setSongLength(duration)
      }
    }

    if (audioRef.current) {
      audioRef.current.pause()
    }

    if (track) {
      audioRef.current = new Audio(currentTrack?.track_file)
      timeOut = setInterval(onPlaying, 100)
      audioRef.current.play()
      audioRef.current.volume = volume / 100
      setIsPlaying(true)
    }

    return () => {
      if (timeOut) {
        clearInterval(timeOut)
      }
    }

  }, [track, currentTrack?.track_file])
```

That's part of code responsible for playing music in general.

I was trying to implement this function, but first I need to figure out how to understand that current track is finished. (This function the way it is works fine with the nextTrack button)

```
const nextTrack = () => {
    setCurrentTrack(tracks[index + 1])
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Where is your react-player in code. Have you trried  ''onEnded  Callback props. Called when media finishes playing. Use this to check to current active tracks. If active track is the last item in array, set next active track to first item. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player

Comment: I modified my code and added onEnded event listener, so now everything is working

Answer (score 0):

Update,
here is the code that works for me, I added eventListener for 'ended'

```
useEffect(() => {
    let timeOut = null

    const onEnded = () => {
      setCurrentTrack(tracks[index + 1])
      dispatch(getCurrentTrack(tracks[index + 1]))
    }

    const onPlaying = () => {
      if (!audioRef.current.paused) {
        const { duration } = audioRef.current
        const { currentTime } = audioRef.current

        setSongProgress((currentTime / duration) * 100)
        setSongLength(duration)
      }
    }

    if (audioRef.current) {
      audioRef.current.pause()
    }

    if (track) {
      audioRef.current = new Audio(currentTrack?.track_file)
      audioRef.current.addEventListener('ended', onEnded)

      timeOut = setInterval(onPlaying, 100)
      audioRef.current.play()
      audioRef.current.volume = volume / 100
      setIsPlaying(true)
    }

    return () => {
      if (timeOut) {
        clearInterval(timeOut)
      }
      if (audioRef.current) {
        audioRef.current.pause()
      }

      if (audioRef.current) {
        audioRef.current.removeEventListener('ended', onEnded)
      }
    }
  }, [track, currentTrack?.track_file, index, dispatch, tracks])
```